# Postgis ST_MAKELINE change dimension of points

Tags: postgis

I have multiple 2D points(lng=X lat=Y altitude=Z==NULL timestamp=M) mixed with multiple 3D points (lng=X lat=Y altitude=Z timestamp=M). I am going to apply `ST_MAKELINE` (Postgis) to those points. Then I realized that function auto fill 0 to Z axis of all 2D points, but I expected NULLs. So is there any function to avoid this?

---

Probably my description was incorrect. I am trying to compress multiple mixed dimension points with `ST_SIMPLIFY`. before I call `ST_SIMPLIFY` I need to make all points into a LINE via `ST_MAKELINE`. Then `ST_MAKELINE` auto convert 2D points into 3D point which is not expected. NULL should be NULL rather than 0.

Pseudo query: `ST_SIMPLIFY(ST_MAKELINE([set of points]))`

Update: What I have done so far (awaiting better solution)

I made a copy of mixed points as raw_points and then convert all mixed points into 2D (basically drop Z) then call `ST_MAKELINE` with all 2D points. Then call `ST_SIMPLIFY` to get a set of compressed points as compressed_points

Finally recover altitude information by following

Pseudo code:

```
select raw_point 
from compressed_point 
 LEFT JOIN raw_points on ST_M(compressed_point) = ST_M(raw_points);
```